# Eclipse RCP: P2 Update feature fails

Tags: eclipse-rcp, p2

I have a prodcut that include 1 feature (application.feature) that contains one plugin with application 
this feature has, in included feature, another one (framework.feature)

if I update framework.feature and one of its plugin I got this error (I use "install new software" to get the correct error, because if I just try to update I go no updates were found)

```
Your original request has been modified.
  "My Framework RCP" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: My Framework RCP 1.0.4 (it.rcp.framework.feature.feature.group 1.0.4)
  Software currently installed: prototipo application 1.0.3 (it.rcp.prototipo.application.product1 1.0.3)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    My Framework RCP 1.0.3 (it.rcp.framework.feature.feature.jar 1.0.3)
    My Framework RCP 1.0.4 (it.rcp.framework.feature.feature.jar 1.0.4)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: My Framework RCP 1.0.3 (it.rcp.framework.feature.feature.group 1.0.3)
    To: it.rcp.framework.feature.feature.jar [1.0.3]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: My Framework RCP 1.0.4 (it.rcp.framework.feature.feature.group 1.0.4)
    To: it.rcp.framework.feature.feature.jar [1.0.4]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: My Application 1.0.3 (it.rcp.prototipo.application.feature.feature.group 1.0.3)
    To: it.rcp.framework.feature.feature.group [1.0.3]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: prototipo application 1.0.3 (it.rcp.prototipo.application.product1 1.0.3)
    To: it.rcp.prototipo.application.feature.feature.group [1.0.3]
```

The two features are separeted in two categories under update site
What's the problem? I think something in my features definition but I don't understand

Answer (score 2):

It means that installed product: "it.sogei.rcp.prototipo.application.product1" depends strictly on version 1.0.3 of the feature: "it.rcp.framework.feature.feature.jar". This is why this feature can't be upgraded to version 1.0.4.

Comment: are you sure? because in application.feature dependencies I put framework.feature with 0.0.0 as version (and not 1.0.3 strictly) that  should mean the last available.

Comment: The feature version on which product depends is formed during build time, and for now products do not support version ranges (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=292542). I think if you produce an update for the application.product as well it should work.

Comment: Hi spektom, I think so, I've already read about versioning product, but the concept I need is: framework.feature  is made from different group than application.feature even if this depends on that, so the product may not change

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is asked long time ago.But I read this post today and replying you. I have already answered this problem. Please check the following post.
[Eclipse RCP Update Fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210293/eclipse-rcp-update/9461031#9461031)